# Problem solving skills and job interviews

Tags: interview

Probably few of you are interviewing wannabe programmers. I'm 28, never worked as a programmer, but spent few months learning C and solving problems. I loved it so much that I do it every day just because I can, now and started studying CS at local university.

Now I'd like to try make living from it and am trying some job interview questions I find on the internet. Some are obvious for me, but some scare me and take me long time to find a solution.

- When you do job interviews, how long you wait for someone to come up with solution? - - Does freezing for some time on problems that take 5-line code disqualify me as a programmer?
- Do you even consider people like me when browsing CV's?
- If you do interview someone like me, what do you ask that person?
- What are your expectations when you meet interviewee like me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had to hire programmers of both junior and senior level. I have different expectations when I interview people, and I customize each interview to the resume and whatever else I find on the candidate online (relative to his/her job skills).

When I present an applicant with a problem I have a specific goal for it, but there are some common things I look for in all programmers once the problem is theirs.

1. Never freeze. Even if you have NO IDEA where to go, attack the problem. Do anything to get yourself started in a direction that will lead to a solution. Even if you go in the wrong direction, you'll be somewhere. If you're asked to write code, come up with a signature, review it, modify it. Try to figure out what technique you'll need to use. Write quick pseudo-code. ANYTHING, just start.
2. Consider each problem fully and in its own context. Write down your assumptions about the problem. Talk to yourself openly while thinking. Don't keep your thoughts to yourself. You are being evaluated on how you solve problems, not the solution you come up with (most of the time), so let the interviewer in on that process.
3. Don't be afraid to fail at solving the problem. You might not be able to solve it. The interviewer might have expressly set you up with a problem you are not expected to be able to solve simply because he wants to see you reason it out (I pull this one all the time though mostly with senior level programmers).
4. For a junior position I consider every CV given to me. I look for markers in the resume that hint that the programmer is driven to learn and try. For someone in your position, I want to see a small portfolio with mini projects that show me self-learning. Texts read, classes taken, etc. I truly don't care about the 4 year degree personally, that's HR's problem. A BS in CS will give a candidate a leg up, but it will also place a higher expectation on that candidate.

As for questions I would ask, I'd have to see something from you first. I tailor each interview to the specific candidate because I am more interested in how the candidate learns and grows more than what they've done (for junior developers). I want a determined individual who will attack problems, learn from failures and can formulate solutions.

Comment: Thank You for all the great tips. I definitelly will put my code somewhere. Is putting own solutions to more complex exercises from handbooks or problems from sites like SPOJ in there good idea?

Comment: @zubergu: It can never hurt. I recommend keeping a public Github repository that you can direct prospective employers to when they ask for code samples or if you just want to show off certain things.

Answer (score 5):

- When you do job interviews, how long you wait for someone to come up with solution?
- Does freezing for some time on problems that take 5-line code disqualify me as a programmer?

There is little point in *waiting* for someone to come up with a solution in an interview - you ask something, and then you want to hear how they reason about it. It is comparatively unimportant whether you *know* an answer or not; this is real life, not school. Virtually everything I'm going to pay you for doing will be new questions, not old ones. Therefore, what counts is how good you are at *getting* to the solution - whether via web search, communication with colleagues, self-education, etc.

- Do you even consider people like me when browsing CV's?
- If you do interview someone like me, what do you ask that person?
- What are your expectations when you meet interviewee like me?

Let me put it this way:

> I loved it so much that I do it every day just because I can, now and started stuying CS at local university

If I could, I would *never, ever* hire someone as a programmer who can't say this of themselves: that they write programs on their own time because they like doing it. I think that this is a much better predictor of how much value you can bring to us than any certification you could name.

Comment: I find your answer very helpful and encouraging.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in hiring a person who never worked as a programmer before, and doesn't have a degree yet. If the person is motivated enough and is able to learn by himself, he can become sooner or later a good programmer or developer.

What are the expectations from a candidate with such profile? The same as for any other candidate:

- Is the person able to program at all?
- What about his communication skills?
- Does the person work better alone or in a team? What are the benefits or flaws of the person when working in a team? Is the person more a leader or somebody who will prefer doing what others tell him to do?
- Is the person knowledgeable enough in a given technology? In other words, how deep are the skills of this person?
- What about other technologies and domains? In other words, how large is the scope of the skills of this person?
- Does the person know how to write clean, maintainable code, or has only experience in writing spaghetti code he can't understand himself six months later?
- What about the experience with the elementary tools such as bug tracking system and version control?

Of course, for a developer, the list would be much larger than for a programmer, and go much deeper.

As for solving problems, there is nothing wrong in taking time to think. I would rather hire somebody who thinks a bit before starting coding than somebody who jumps to the first idea which gets into his mind, no matter how good or bad it is.

Comment: Unfortunatelly 0 experience with tools in the last point. I never wrote anything that complex to use them on my own. But thanks for the tip, I will at least read about git and SVN for starters.

Comment: @zubergu: there is no complexity threshold to use version control. In the same way, you don't need to work with another person on a project in order to use it.